# How to return new markers coordinates changed in separated window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following link:

```
<a href="#" id="context-map" onclick="showMap(57.8166994,28.33447339999998)">choose on map</a>
```

`showMap`  accepts geocoding coordinates and shows marker at this place.

```
function showMap(lat,lng) {
    window.open('map?lat='+lat+'&lng='+lng, 'map', 'width=600,height=400');
}
```

on map.jsp i have following js:

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng("${lat}","${lng}");
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: myLatlng
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map            
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });
    function placeMarker(location) {
        marker.setMap(null);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
        });
    }
}
```

I want to achieve that after I have changed marker position on map this change should affect showMap arguments

```
showMap(changedMarkerLat, changedMarkerLng)
```

Comment: Why would't you try the approach with public variables instead of providing arguments?

Comment: @esc Please provide more details

Comment: Question doesn't make sense as it is written. Please explain your higher level objective. If you are trying to send data back to parent window, look at using postMessage API

Comment: So call getPosition() on the marker object and then call the function?

Answer (score 0):

Possible approach: instead of passing lat/lng as parameters to the function(as suggested by @esc), store these data somewhere and access them inside the function.

Example:(stores the lat/lng as attributes of the link)

```
<a href="#" id="context-map" 
   data-lat="57.8166994" 
   data-lng="28.33447339999998" 
   onclick="showMap(this)">choose on map</a>
```

---

```
function showMap(o) {
    //you only need to open a new window when its not open yet
    if(!o.map ||o.map.closed){
      o.map = window.open('map?lat='+o.getAttribute('data-lat')+
                          '&lng='+o.getAttribute('data-lng'), 
                          'map', 
                          'width=600,height=400');
    }
    //otherwise only bring the window into front
    else{
      o.map.focus();
    }

}
```

Inside the new window set the `data-lat` and `data-lng`-attributes of the link

```
function initialize() { 

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng("${lat}","${lng}");
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: myLatlng
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map            
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });
    function placeMarker(location) {
        try{//use a try-catch to avoid errors when the opener has been closed
          var link=opener.document.getElementById('context-map');
          link.setAttribute('data-lat',location.lat());
          link.setAttribute('data-lng',location.lng());
        }catch(e){}
        //there's no need to create a new Marker,
        //simply update the position of the existing Marker
        marker.setPosition(location);

    }
}
```

Demo: http://www.googledrive.com/host/0BwPgjOA-i5WyQ0VmR3JZTU9BS0U